# Search Optimization on SPListItemCollection

Tags: development, splistitem, spquery, splistitemcollection

I have an SPListItemCollection (Thread Discussion Collection) that consists of almost 20,000 items. Each SPListItem (Thread Discussion) on the SPListItemCollection contains a sub SPListItem(Thread Discussion Replies).

I wanted to optimized the speed of the search on the replies. On my current setup,
I loop on each discussion and use search for replies that contains the word that I am looking for. Is there a way the I could speed this up? The for each loop on the main discussion thread itself would already consume a lot of memory.

Here is my code snippet

```
List<string> lstResult = new List<string>();
string strSearch = "programming";
SPList spList = spWeb.List["DiscussionList"];
/// list of discussions
SPListItemCollection DiscussionList = spList.Items;
foreach(SPListItem Discussion in DiscussionList){
    string searchQuery = string.Concat("<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Body' /><Value Type='Note'>", strSearch, "</Value></Contains></Where>");
    SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
    spQuery.Query = searchQuery;
    SPListItemCollection Replies = spList.GetItems(spQuery);
    foreach(SPListItem reply in Replies){
        lstResult.Add(lstResults.reply["Body"].ToString());
    }
}

/// return result
return lstResult;
```

Note: I already use RowLimit so it's a given scenario for a search. I did not include it here because it's not the solution that I'm looking for. I'm looking for a better way of querying items. Somewhat like

Select AllDiscussion From DiscussionList Where Discussion.Replies contains 'search'

I just don't know if it is possible. A miracle might help :D

Answer (score 1):

Okay straight of why did you include both for loop and spquery remove the for loop for the list items , i.e on  foreach(SPListItem Discussion in DiscussionList) , use only spquery since you are searching on the discussion list anyways. Also , if it helps you can use rowlimit on Spquery class f you dont want all the items.

Modified code would look like :

```
List<string> lstResult = new List<string>();
string strSearch = "programming";
SPList spList = spWeb.List["DiscussionList"];
/// list of discussions
SPListItemCollection DiscussionList = spList.Items;

string searchQuery = string.Concat("<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Body' /><Value     Type='Note'>", strSearch, "</Value></Contains></Where>");
SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
spQuery.Query = searchQuery;
SPListItemCollection Replies = spList.GetItems(spQuery);
foreach(SPListItem reply in Replies){
    lstResult.Add(lstResults.reply["Body"].ToString());
}


return lstResult;
```

Comment: If you just try to understand the situation. DiscussionList is a list of SPListItem that's why I looped through all the items inside the discussionList because each item contains a collection of replies. "Replies" is a subfolder inside the Discussion and DiscussionList is a collection of Discussion. I'm actually doing a search inside the folder Replies which is actually a subfolder of discussion. I hope I'm clear on that. :)

Comment: Yup , now it makes sense. Then i would suggest RowLimit under SPQuery , in case you are displaying not all but something like the latest replies. 20,000  is a pretty big amount. Gotta love large lists in sp2010

Comment: Actually I already have the row limit applied. I am hoping to see an answer somewhat like this (select AllDiscussion from DiscussionList where DiscussionList.Replies contains 'programming') if I could only do this on CAML query. But I guess not :( Rowlimit is given already, I initially display max of 20 items per query. :)

Comment: ouch , then id advice you to take a look at http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx it helps build caml queries, feed in the relations and lets see .

Comment: haha I'm using CamlQueryBuilder too but it only gives me simple queries it does not include complicated queries that could possible complicate my life lol

Comment: okay , i gave you all i could . now i really want to know how we can solve this problem. im keeping track of this question :). All the best. Btw have you calculated how much time it takes to execute this code?

Comment: Yes, and it's about a freaking 45-60 seconds per bloody search. The older code doesn't use any caml query it's just purely loop and it takes more than a minute. Now it's a little faster but it's still considered as a fast running turtle...bloody hell...hahaha

Comment: true true , 45-60 secs is a biggie. lets see how this goes..

Comment: Okay, tnx for the help :)